# Where is http://repo1.maven.org/maven2

Tags: maven

As is well known http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 is no longer available and returns HTTP 501 and tells you to use SSL https://repo1.maven.org/maven2. The trick of adding the HTTPS link to settings.xml is not working for us (see below).

We have a project which does NOT have a pom.xml and are baffled as to where this URL is defined. We have changed it in `apache-ant-1.9.1\lib\libraries.properties` to no avail.

Our build uses gradle and we have gradle and maven pointing to a custom artifact proxy. Still we get build warnings and errors pointing to `http://`repo.maven.org/maven2 Where on earth is this coming from?

Our build process runs on an azure devops vm `ubuntu-latest` (is it possible microsoft provides an old maven version with the http link?) and our `.m2/settings.xml` are as follows:

```xml
<settings>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>centralhttps</id>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
      <name>Maven central https</name>
      <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>ourcompany-external</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Our Maven Repo</name>
      <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ourcompany/_packaging/ourcompany-external/maven/v1/</url>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
      <id>ourcompany-custom</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>Our Maven Repo</name>
      <url>https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/ourcompany/_packaging/ourcompany-custom/maven/v1/</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>ourcompany-external</id>
      <username>***</username>
      <password>***</password>
    </server>
    <server>
      <id>ourcompany-custom</id>
      <username>***</username>
      <password>***</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

The reason we have 2 company mirrors is that the external one is for caching and the custom one is where we can upload our own artifacts and zips. It would seem that maven [docs](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html) doesn't like 2 mirrors having `<mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>` but what value should we use for 2 mirrors that both need to be checked?

Why is it trying http:// if this is nowhere configured?

### Logs

```
[artifact:mvn] Downloading: org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-file/2.8/wagon-file-2.8.pom from repository centralhttps at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
[artifact:mvn] Downloading: org/eclipse/aether/aether-transport-wagon/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.pom from repository centralhttps at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
[artifact:mvn] Transferring 4K from centralhttps
[artifact:mvn] [INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.eclipse.aether:aether-transport-wagon:pom:1.0.0.v20140518' in repository centralhttps (https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/)
[artifact:mvn] Downloading: org/eclipse/aether/aether-transport-wagon/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.pom from repository central at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2
[artifact:mvn] Error transferring file: Server returned HTTP response code: 501 for URL: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/aether/aether-transport-wagon/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.pom
[artifact:mvn] [WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.eclipse.aether:aether-transport-wagon:pom:1.0.0.v20140518' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: Server returned
...
[artifact:mvn] Downloading: org/eclipse/aether/aether-transport-wagon/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.jar from repository centralhttps at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
[artifact:mvn] Transferring 25K from centralhttps
```

Comment: maybe http is just a fallback? your artifact doesn't seem to be found with https either: "[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.eclipse.aether:aether-transport-wagon:pom:1.0.0.v20140518' in repository centralhttps (`https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/`)"

Comment: also, if your build is using gradle and you're asking about that, then you need to provide the gradle buildfile for anyone to be able to comment on that

Comment: We are using gradle which calls ant which calls maven so it's complicated. All the gradle stuff works fine as gradle allows you to specify multiple repos and it checks each one. Maven apparently does not.

Comment: HTTPS works fine: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/aether/aether-transport-wagon/1.0.0.v20140518/aether-transport-wagon-1.0.0.v20140518.pom

Comment: based on your logs, it doesn't work find, since your build is not able to find it. And ok, provide the pom.xml file then. But your setup seems messy as hell :D

Comment: It is messy, we can't change it (it's a platform) and we don't have *a* pom, we have hundreds of external-dependencies.xml which are treated as poms. The problem however is not these poms, since they don't reference URLs but the superpom which does reference URLs.

Comment: yes, I was expecting the poms themselves probably don't. But you'd need to provide the superpom that is referencing the urls then, at least the relevant parts.